# Elasticsearch aggregation using Java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to do query on elastic search by following the sql query and I want to implement same logic using Java API

```
select dttime, avg(cpu) from table cpustats where server="X" and dttime="Y" group by dttime,cpu
```

Now I have the following Java code but it does not return expected output

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("cpuindex")
      .setTypes("cputype")
      .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
      .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("cpu_agg")
           .field("cpu").size(100))
      .execute().actionGet();
```

Please guide I am new to Elastic search. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this will help.

```
SearchResponse response=
                client.prepareSearch("your_index_name_here").setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
                FilterBuilders.andFilter(
                        FilterBuilders.termFilter("server","x"),
                        FilterBuilders.termFilter("dt_time","x")
                ))).addAggregation(
                AggregationBuilders.terms("dt_timeaggs").field("dt_time").size(100).subAggregation(
                        AggregationBuilders.terms("cpu_aggs").field("cpu").size(100)
                )
        ).setSize(0).get();
```

please verify.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have doubt what is requestBuilder here? New to Java APIs of elasticsearch its difficult to find what is it. Please guide.

Comment: its, what client.prepareSearch() returns.

Comment: See, i've changed my answer. If it solved your problem then accept it ??

Comment: I am working on it query fails it is not returning any results. Sure I will accept your answer once it is working I will edit it for others reference.

Comment: what's your data look like?

Answer (score 2):

since elastic search 2.3, FilterBuilders class has been removed from JavaAPI. you can use

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("_all", "JPMORGAN"))
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field, value)) ;
```

instead, and set it to

```
.setQuery(qb).
```